# Не получается отрисовать модель

Tags: java, opengl, opengles, lwjgl

Нужно определить находится ли треугольники модели(орел) внутри прямоугольной плоскости. Написал программу, но отрисовка почему- то работает плохо. В чем причина?

`matrCoord` - Вершина треугольника, `projMatrCopy`  - матрица проекции **P * V * M**. Получаю новые координаты вершины треугольника модели:

```
private Vector3f getVector(int pos) {
        Matrix4f projMatrCopy = new Matrix4f().set(proj);
        Matrix4f matrCoord = new Matrix4f(new Vector4f(positions[pos], positions[pos + 1], positions[pos + 2], 1.0f),
                new Vector4f(0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Vector4f(0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Vector4f(0,0,0, 0));
        Vector4f p1 = new Vector4f();
        projMatrCopy.mul(matrCoord).getColumn(0, p1);
        return new Vector3f(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z);
    }
```

И далее эту вершину проверяю на то, что находится ли она внутри прямоугольной области. Делаю это так:

```
private boolean intersectsPlaneToPoint(Vector3f point, List<Vector4f> planes) {

        Float d1 = Intersectionf.distancePointPlane(point.x, point.y, point.z,planes.get(0).x,planes.get(0).y,planes.get(0).z,planes.get(0).w);
        Float d2 = Intersectionf.distancePointPlane(point.x, point.y, point.z, planes.get(1).x,planes.get(1).y,planes.get(1).z,planes.get(1).w);
        Float d3 = Intersectionf.distancePointPlane(point.x, point.y, point.z, planes.get(2).x,planes.get(2).y,planes.get(2).z,planes.get(2).w);
        Float d4 = Intersectionf.distancePointPlane(point.x, point.y, point.z, planes.get(3).x,planes.get(3).y,planes.get(3).z,planes.get(3).w);
        Float d5 = Intersectionf.distancePointPlane(point.x, point.y, point.z, planes.get(4).x,planes.get(4).y,planes.get(4).z,planes.get(4).w);
        Float d6 = Intersectionf.distancePointPlane(point.x, point.y, point.z,planes.get(5).x,planes.get(5).y,planes.get(5).z,planes.get(5).w);
        return d1 < 0 && d2 < 0 && d3 < 0 && d4 >= 0 && d5 < 0 && d6 >= 0;
    }
```

`planes.get(0).x,planes.get(0).y,planes.get(0).z,planes.get(0).w` - 
это **a b c d** компоненты плоскости

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы вот пробовали то же самое сделать, только с меньшим количеством кода? (`Matrix4f.project()`, если я не ошибаюсь)

Comment: @selya а это что за функция, расскажите, пожалуйста поподробнее

Comment: аналог устаревшей `gluProject`, о которой можете почитать в тырнете. Вернет вам 4-х мерные координаты. Берите x и y - это и будут координаты на экране.

Comment: Забыл уточнить. Если вы берете координату в пространстве модели и используете MVP матрицу, то все будет работать. Если же координата уже в пространстве мира, то матрицу нужно брать VP, очевидно. А получив x,y в экранных координатах уже легко проверить, попадают ли они в необходимый прямоугольник.

Comment: @selya Я работаю только с экранными координатами

Comment: Как это вы работаете только с экранными координатами, если я вижу у вас в коде матрицы, тем более матрицу проекции, трёхмерные координаты, какие-то плейны? И что за плейны? Их 6, вы явно проверяете точку на нахождение внутри параллелепипеда, а не прямоугольника. В общем, не особо-то понятно. Да и плоскость прямоугольной быть явно не может, если уже совсем придираться к терминам)

Comment: @selya верно параллелепипед . Но координаты в рамках OpenGL я не стал переводить их в мировые

Comment: `d1 < 0 && d2 < 0 && d3 < 0 && d4 >= 0 && d5 < 0 && d6 >= 0` вот тут почему-то 4 "меньше" и 2 "больше-или-равно". А должно то быть 3 и 3 .. по идее. Объясните или исправите?

Comment: @Kromster конкретно так более менее отрисовывает. если как то по другому знаки раскидать не отрисовывает вообще

Comment: Попробуйте для начала ограничиться только 1 плоскостью - например левой. По ней разделите все что слева и все что справа и проверьте что верно рисуется/раскрашивается.

Comment: @selya я так и делаю . использую матрицу проекции и координаты модели.

Comment: @Санаев я вам скажу, что вы делаете ерунду. Я понятия не имею, что это за преобразования координат вы делаете. Если хотите, чтобы вам помогли, опишите задачу правильно и полно: напишите, что дано, напишите, что необходимо сделать. Что сделано, можете не писать, ибо я тут вижу только какие-то неясные трансформации. Отредактируйте ответ, и я постараюсь помочь. Хотя бы опишите, что делает функция `getVector`. Она возвращает координату в мировом пространстве по индексу вершины модели? Тогда вы делаете направильно.